# How to import Scipy and Numpy in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am very new to Python and want to add Numpy and Scipy module. I think my question is very simple for you. I am using Python 3.06a.1 version. I think I already installed something called Anaconda that contains those library. When I type import scipy I get the following message:

```
import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

also when I want to installed with command line I get the following message which means that I have it already.

```
   localhost:~ user$ pip install scipy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
localhost:~ user$
```

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: Err... Your pip installation says `spicy`, not `scipy`!?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo @NilsGudat

Comment: 3.06a.1 doesn't look like a valid version name, where did you see that ?

Comment: at the header window of IDLE its written Pythin 3.6.0a1 shell @polku

Comment: Well 3.6.0a1 is not the same as 3.06a.1. So you have an alpha version of python3.6.  Anaconda uses Spyder as an IDE, have you tried with it ?

Comment: `which pip` `which python`

Comment: I didnt know that I should lunch anaconda app to run my code. I was trying with IDLE. Now its running, thanks @polku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have problem with scipy and numpy if you installed Anaconda. What I'm advising you may sound stupid, but I'm sure it has a good chance to solve your problem.

Relaunch Anaconda, reboot your computer, reinstall Anaconda.

Edit : also watch out to use "scipy" and not "spicy" as I just witnessed in your logs.

Comment: I didnt know that I should lunch anaconda app to run my code. I was trying with IDLE. Now its running, thanks @pierre-louis-sauvage

Answer (score 4):

if you are using anaconda, try installing scipy using anaconda:

```
conda install scipy
```